# How to create PowerBI waterfall charts showing a target profit, amounts above and below budget, and the actual profit?

Tags: charts, powerbi

I would like to create a waterfall chart in PowerBI that starts with the value expected for profit in the budget, then shows variances against budget in both directions, then shows the actual profit made. This is what it looks like in Excel, with the target and actuals "Set as Total".

[image: example from Excel of what I want it to look like]

This is easy to do in Excel but from Googling there is apparently no "Set Total" option in PowerBI's normal Waterfall chart option?

[This is the best option I have found so far - download Ultimate Waterfall and use that](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Waterfall-Chart-Set-as-total/td-p/2768351). But Ultimate Waterfall shows a watermark/charges/and I can't seem to set the original Total to have the name I want - it just shows as "Starting Value" rather than as the target profit for the month.

Are there better options within PowerBI? Thanks!

Comment: what is your database? is budget and actual in two tables?

Comment: The original data is in a single table but it would be easy to split it into two and do it that way if it would help?

Comment: Nono, I do not want it in two tables just want to know your database so can fingure out how to do it. Let me see your single table looks like.

Comment: As the above is just an example, I just made it with a two column table in Excel. CSV is this text:


Target profit June,"10,000"
Revenue,"2,500"
Staff costs,(700)
Tech costs,"(1,200)"
Marketing costs,"1,000"
Actual profit June,"11,600"

Answer (score 1):

**Two ways for your visual:**

**1. Add [Index] column in PowerQuery for order:**

[image]

**2. Set Item column sort by Index:**

[image]

**3. [option1: use standard waterfall visual]**

*"Target profit" bar cannot change color and "Actual profit" bar cannot change name*

[image]

1. Set waterfall sort axis as 'sort ascending by item':

[image]

2. Filter page remove "Actual profit" and visual setting page open "Show total column"

[image]

**3. [option2: use Stacked Column chart visual]**

*all bars name are correct but colors cannot change*

[image]

***two columns calculation formula:***

```
Value assist = SWITCH(TRUE(),
[Index]=1,0,
[Index]=2,
    IF([Value]>0,
    CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=1,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall')), 
    CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=1,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+[Value]),
[Index]=3,
    IF([Value]>0,
    CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=1,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=2,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall')),
    CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=1,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=2,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+[Value]),
[Index]=4,
    IF([Value]>0,
    CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=1,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=2,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=3,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall')),
    CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=1,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=2,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=3,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+[Value]),
[Index]=5,
    IF([Value]>0,
    CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=1,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=2,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=3,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=4,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall')),
    CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=1,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=2,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=3,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+CALCULATE(SUM([Value]),'Waterfall'[Index]=4,REMOVEFILTERS('Waterfall'))+[Value]),
[Index]=6,0)
```

- 

```
Value 2 = ABS([Value])
```

Comment: Bit late coming back on this one, but thanks, Sia! Very helpful.